# c# byte array back into the original 3 floats

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to decode my Temp/Humid/Bat payload that I am pulling out of AuzreIOT Hub. Here is a sample method I am using in C# to parse the byte array. Once I have parsed it, how do I convert those numbers back into decimal values?

Here is the input data on the sensor side:

```
T=74.48
RH=45.20
BatteryVoltage:3332
```

Here is how the data was input (in C):

```
float temperature = readDHTTemperature(); //this method prints T to Serial
float humidity = readDHTHumidity(); //this method prints H to Serial
uint16_t batteryVoltage = readBattery(true);
delay(100);

unsigned char *puc;

puc = (unsigned char *)(&temperature);
appDataSize = 10;
appData[0] = puc[0];
appData[1] = puc[1];
appData[2] = puc[2];
appData[3] = puc[3];


puc = (unsigned char *)(&humidity);
appData[4] = puc[0];
appData[5] = puc[1];
appData[6] = puc[2];
appData[7] = puc[3];

appData[8] = (uint8_t)(batteryVoltage>>8);
appData[9] = (uint8_t)batteryVoltage;
```

Here is my output attempt in C#:

```
private static void BytesToString()
{
    var hexStringFromPayLoad = "MzOYQgAAHEINBA==";
    var bytes = Base64Decode(hexStringFromPayLoad);

    Console.WriteLine($"Temp: {bytes[0]}, {bytes[1]}, {bytes[2]}, {bytes[3]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Humid: {bytes[4]}, {bytes[5]}, {bytes[6]}, {bytes[7]}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Bat: {bytes[8]}, {bytes[9]}");

    /*
    Temp: 51, 51, 152, 66
    Humid: 0, 0, 28, 66
    Bat: 13, 4
    */

//I need
// T=74.48 
// RH=45.20 
// BatteryVoltage:3332
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that input string/byte array is correct for that desired output? See this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VuTIuX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is **BitConverter** of the .net **System** namespace

Example:

```
 static void BytesToString() {
   
   byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 51, 51, 152, 66, 0, 0, 28, 66, 13, 4 };

   float temperature = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
   float humidity = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 4);
   ushort batteryVoltage = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 8);
   
   ...
 }

}
```

Comment: That results in `Temp = 76.1, Hum = 39, Battery = 1037` which isn't what the OP is expecting - perhaps the endianess needs to be accounted for.

Comment: Thank you both for chiming in.  Turns out the Big Indian is the battery.